# Create dummy-column based on another columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, dummy-variable

Let's say I have this dataset

```
> example <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 10:1, c = 1:5 )
```

I want to create a new variable `d`. I want in `d` the value 1 when at least in of the variables `a b c` the value 1 2 or 3 is present.
`d` should look like this:

```
d <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` to get a logical vector of `1, 2 or 3` appearing in each row and wrap it in `as.integer` to convert to 0 and 1, i.e.

```
as.integer(rowSums(df == 1|df == 2| df == 3) > 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using apply(although little slow)

**Logic**: `any` will compare if there is any 1,2 or 3 is present or not, `apply` is used to iterate this logic on each of the rows. Then finally converting the boolean outcome to numeric by adding +0 (You may choose `as.numeric` here in case you want to be more expressive)

```
d <- apply(example,1 ,function(x)any(x==1|x==2|x==3))+0
```

In case someone wants to restrict the columns or want to run the logic on some columns, then one can do this also:

```
d <- apply(example[,c("a","b","c")], 1, function(x)any(x==1|x==2|x==3))+0
```

Here you have control on columns on which one to take or ignore basis your needs.

**Output**:

```
> d
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What if I would have a 4th variable, but I do not care what is in there. With "any" values of 1,2,3 in the forth variable would be considered too....

Comment: @AmelioTornincasa , Yes this would iterate on every variable present on your data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Will work for any number of vars:

```
example <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 10:1, c = 1:5 )
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
as.integer(Reduce(function(a, b) (a %in% x) | (b %in% x), example))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other possibilities which work with any number of columns:

```
#option 1
example$d <- +(rowSums(sapply(example, `%in%`, 1:3)) > 0)

#option 2
library(matrixStats)
example$d <- rowMaxs(+(sapply(example, `%in%`, 1:3)))
```

which both give:

> ```
> > example
>     a  b c d
> 1   1 10 1 1
> 2   2  9 2 1
> 3   3  8 3 1
> 4   4  7 4 0
> 5   5  6 5 0
> 6   6  5 1 1
> 7   7  4 2 1
> 8   8  3 3 1
> 9   9  2 4 1
> 10 10  1 5 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

With the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- 1:3
example %>% mutate(d = as.integer(a %in% x | b %in% x | c %in% x))
```

Answer (score 0):

general solution:

```
example %>%
sapply(function(i)i %in% x) %>% apply(1,any) %>% as.integer
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this method, verify if in any column there is at list one element present in `x`.

```
x<-c(1,2,3)
example$d<-as.numeric(example$a %in% x | example$b %in% x | example$c %in% x)
example
    a  b c d
1   1 10 1 1
2   2  9 2 1
3   3  8 3 1
4   4  7 4 0
5   5  6 5 0
6   6  5 1 1
7   7  4 2 1
8   8  3 3 1
9   9  2 4 1
10 10  1 5 1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: This is the best answer - simple, fast, clear code. Not sure why it got voted down. Using `apply`, `dplyr` etc. here is overkill. If you had 10 columns, that might be different.

Comment: Thank you @dash2. All the other answer are running good, but in mine the questioner can find also the output integrated in its original data.frame and I suppose this is what he wants.